# Make custom document display correct "Kind" Attribute in macOS Finder instead of "DocumentType"

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, finder, document-based

In a document-based app, I create files with a custom UTI and extension. I declare both of these in the target's Info>Document Types and Info>Exported UTIs panes, as captured in the image below.

I am able to locate those files in finder, and they display the correct extension, as well as open in the app appropriately. However, they still display their "kind" attribute as "DocumentType" in finder.

Is that an issue in what I've declared in xCode, or something that needs to be refreshed in my mac's finder? Does anybody see a problem with how these are entered in XCode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ah, wait. I had to edit the conforms to field to read "public.data".  That seems to have fixed it.